# How to use regex substitution with non-capturing group in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

```py
import pdfplumber, requests, re, io
def pdf_extracted_txt(url, page):
    rq = requests.get(url)
    pdf = pdfplumber.load(io.BytesIO(rq.content))
    txt = pdf.pages[page].extract_text()
    return txt

def remove_noise(txt):
    pattern = r'^.{1,3}$|(^.{1,3})(?:\s[A-Z])|\s+.{1,2}$'
    noiseRegx = re.compile(pattern, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    txt = noiseRegx.sub(r'',txt)
    txt = re.sub('\n+','\n',txt)
    print(txt)

url, page = 'https://www1.hkexnews.hk/listedco/listconews/sehk/2020/0428/2020042800976.pdf', 60
txt = pdf_extracted_txt(url, page)
remove_noise(txt)
```

I want to remove the noise in the extracted text such that the last three rows will be

```
PricewaterhouseCoopers
Certified Public Accountants
Hong Kong, 26 March 2020
```

however, the code replaces `\s[A-Z]` and seems the noncapturing work is not taking any effect.
The current output is

```
ricewaterhouseCoopers
ertified Public Accountants
ong Kong, 26 March 2020
```

Here is the [regex and text](https://regex101.com/r/UdQ6wF/1).
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You could try this as the middle part of the pattern `^\S{1,3}\s(?=[A-Z])` but note that the alternation consists of 3 parts which also has matches at the top of the text. https://regex101.com/r/rV3tgs/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I think it answers my question. would you mind answering the question? It would be great if you would explain the advantage of using `\S` over `.`(wildcard) in this case. Thank you!

Comment: I can add it an answer, it would also work with `.` which would match any char including a space. The `\S` matches non whitespace chars, it depends on what you would allow before the 3 values at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of the pattern `(^.{1,3})(?:\s[A-Z])` captures any char (including a space) 1 - 3 times in a group followed by matching a whitespace char and an uppercase char.

If you replace the whole match with an empty string, the space and the uppercase char are also removed, that is why they are missing in the output.

Depending on what you want to allow to match, you could for example match 1-3 times a non whitepace char and use a positive lookahead to assert what is directly to the right is a whitespace char and an uppercase char `[A-Z]`

```
^.{1,3}$|^\S{1,3}\s(?=[A-Z])|\s+.{1,2}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rV3tgs/1)

You could also keep the dot, but then it would also match for example

`Hong Kong, 26 March 2020`